# decode raw video data with meta data using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have raw video files where each frame consists of:

- 64 bytes of meta-data, followed by
- image data (1920x1080 uyvy422)

I would like to use `ffmpeg` (or really any other simple method) to

- extract the image data into `png` files
- dump the 64 bytes meta-data per frame really in any way

What I have tried is

```
ffmpeg -pixel_format uyvy422 -video_size 1920x1080 -i input_file.bin out_dir/frame-%3d.png
```

This is almost correct, except that it does not skip over the 64 bytes of meta data between frames.

Is this possible with `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is this possible with ffmpeg?`

No. ffmpeg has no way to know this metadata exists, and there is no option to describe an arbitrary format outside of modifying the ffmpeg source code. You will need to write a program that reads the files, extracts the metadata and pipes the video to ffmpeg.